# strip string after character

Tags: sql, teradata

Hello i have a column with a string value that looks like `test ( test):5` and i want to strip everything after `:` including this character.

I have the below sql and keep getting this error:

> [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.26] [Error 3706] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error: expected something between '(' and the string ':'.

```
select blah, LEFT(blah, CHARINDEX(':', blah) - 1) AS newblah from blah_table
```

can someone please help?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Teradata doesn't support the `LEFT` string function before 15.10, but this must not be negative. `CHAR_INDEX` is SQL Server proprietary syntax, `POSITION` is Standard SQL/Teradata:

```
-- will fail if there's no ':' because FOR must be >= 0
SUBSTRING(blah FROM 1 FOR (POSITION('0' in blah) - 1))

-- will work because FROM might be negative, too 
SUBSTRING(blah FROM 0 FOR (POSITION('0' in blah)))
```

What do you want to return if there's no `':'`?

The SUBSTRING will return an empty string, if you want the full string instead better use:

```
-- tokenize the string and return the 1st token
STRTOK(blah, ':', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is right ... at least in sql server ... not sure about teradata.

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(blah, 0, LEN(blah) - CHARINDEX (':', blah))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work for you on Teradata:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(blah FROM 1 FOR (POSITION(';' in blah) - 1));
```